# How do I return the sum after going through each product?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

How do I make it resolve the final sum after it has gone through each product?

At the moment `return sum;` is returning `0`. Which I can understand, because `this.get('product')` is `async`.

Do I need to use an `RSVP`? Or other approach?

```
  subtotalInCents: function () {
    var sum = 0;

    this.get('items').forEach(function(item) {
      item.get('product').then(function(product){
        sum += item.get('count') * product.get('amountInCents');
        console.log(sum);
      });
    });

    return sum;
  }.property('items.@each.count'),
```

Comment: can you share your console.log?

Comment: @Nikos `console.log` outputs the right values. i.e. `21371`, `35767`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Use observer instead.

```
subtotalInCents: 0,

didItemsChange: function () {
    var that = this;
    var items = this.get('items');    
    var itemCount = items.get('length');
    var sum = 0;

    items.forEach(function(item) {
      item.get('product').then(function(product){
        sum += item.get('count') * product.get('amountInCents');
        itemCount--;
        if (itemCount === 0) {
          that.set('subtotalInCents', sum);
        };
      });
    });

  }.observes('items.@each.count')
```

Comment: I am curious as to why you chose to use an observer and not a computed property? Can it not be done using a computed property?

Comment: I felt observer way more easy. You can also return a promise which template can handle. I'll try that in some time or you can also try it.

Comment: It is a good solution, no doubt. I am equally intrigued to see how this can be done via a computed property

Comment: this link http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/promises-and-computed-properties/3333 can be more helpful in understanding why you should use observer instead of property in this case. 
In your case value is returned before it was set. Since you're having multiple promises in foreach loop, you can return a promise which can wait till last promise to resolve. Then again wherever you're using this property has to be promise aware such as in template.